# How to prove inverse of a linear operator is diagonalizable using concept of eigenspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let **T** be an invertible linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space **V**.

Given for any eigenvalue $\alpha$ of **T**, $\alpha$^(-1) is an eigenvalue of **T^(-1)**. I first proved that the eigenspace of **T** corresponding to eigenvalue  $\alpha$ is the same as the eigenspace of **T^(-1)** corresponding to $\alpha$^(-1).
Now I need to prove that if **T** is diagonalizable, then **T^(-1)** is also diagonalizable.

I feel that given that **T** is invertible and diagonalizable it has a basis $\beta$ consisting of distinct eigenvectors of T. This is where I am stuck. Would I be right in saying that **T^(-1)** will also have the same basis $\beta$? And hence prove it is diagonalizable?
I only know that the eigenspaces are same for both the operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is basically correct. Since $0$ is not an eigenvector of $T$ (if this is not obvious to you, you should think about proving it), *every* eigenvector of $T$ is also an eigenvector of $T^{-1}$. There exists by hypothesis a basis consisting of eigenvectors for $T$, and that basis is also a basis of eigenvectors for$~T^{-1}$.

It depends on how diagonalisable was defined for you. For me it is defined as admitting a basis consisting of eigenvectors. You could also define it by saying that the sum of all eigenspaces is the whole space. Then again, since the eigenspaces of $T$ and of $T^{-1}$ are in fact the same, it is obvious that $T$ diagonalisable implies $T^{-1}$ is. This is not really different, but at least the concept of eigenspaces is mentioned.

Comment: Yes Sir I got your point. Even I am following the definition of diagonalizability in the sense of existence of a basis consisting of distinct eigenvectors of that operator.

Comment: But try not to say "distinct" in connection with "basis". Doing so suggests that you don't realise that vectors in a basis are _always_ distinct. And the word "distinct" is often used in connection with "eigenvalues", but that would be wrong here: the eigenvectors do not have to be for disinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Point noted Sir. I do absolutely realise that vectors in a basis are necessarily distinct. Might have been a habit to emphasise that with this word "distinct". But I do realise it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Concretely, if $T = UDU^{-1}$, then $T^{-1} = UD^{-1}U^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes I know this property! But my question requires me to prove this using the concept of eigenspaces. So can I safely assume they share the same basis because they have the same eigenspace?

Comment: Slight nitpick: Actually $T$ is a linear operator, not a matrix.

Comment: @ShikhaSafaya: Right, what I wanted to say with it is that the column vectors of the diagonalizing matrix $U$ are eigenvectors of $T$, and that the same matrix works for $T^{-1}$.

Marc van Leeuwen: Yeah, fair point; assuming a basis given of course ruins the question a little bit. As you say yourself, the precise definition of course plays a role here.

Comment: @fuglede the only reason why I am assuming a basis is that the former part of the question required me to show that they have the same eigenspace. So I took an arbitrary element and already proved that it will belong to both the eigenspaces.